# Not able to use a Variable inside a nested function in R

Tags: r, function, plyr

I have been writing a function which has to find the unique values 
from a particular column after grouping based on couple of columns.

lets say i have the below sample data

```
head(Adult_data[,c(2,10,1)],20)
               workclass     sex age
    1          State-gov    Male  39
    2   Self-emp-not-inc    Male  50
    3            Private    Male  38
    4            Private    Male  53
    5            Private  Female  28
    6            Private  Female  37
    7            Private  Female  49
    8   Self-emp-not-inc    Male  52
    9            Private  Female  31
    10           Private    Male  42
    11           Private    Male  37
    12         State-gov    Male  30
    13           Private  Female  23
    14           Private    Male  32
    15           Private    Male  40
    16           Private    Male  34
    17  Self-emp-not-inc    Male  25
    18           Private    Male  32
    19           Private    Male  38
    20  Self-emp-not-inc  Female  43
>
```

I want to count the number of UNIQUE "Age" values ,So i wrote a 
function to group and used ddply to find the unique values inside my 
function..
something like this ,

```
  U=function(File_name,W,S,A) {
  File_name=read.csv("Adult_data_Set.csv")

  Out1=File_name[[W]]
  Out2=File_name[[S]]
  Out3=File_name[[A]]

  library(plyr); library(dplyr)
A=ddply(File_name,~File_name[[W]]+File_name[[S]],summarize,new=length(unique(File_name[[A]])))
  print(A)


}

U(Adult_data_Set.csv,"workclass","sex","age")
```

It s throwing an error as below

```
U(Adult_data_Set.csv,"workclass","sex","age")

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'File_name' not found
```

I have even tried like this inside the function instead of ddply but 
not giving the expected results

```
library(dplyr)
UNQ=as.data.frame(File_name %>%
  group_by(File_name[[W]],File_name[[S]]) %>%
  summarise(n_distinct(File_name[[A]])))

print(UNQ)
```

but when we hard code the values in the function , it is working 
perfectly ..

Could you please help me out on how to pass the variables inside a 
function as arguments. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to quote your filename... `U("Adult_data_Set.csv","workclass","sex","age")`, otherwise it thinks you are passing it a value stored in a variable called `Adult_data_Set.csv`, which it cannot find.  In your function definition, you have this hardcoded anyway, so I'm not sure why you are passing the filename.

Comment: Andrew is correct. You might also find the split function useful as a base-r/non-dplr alternative: `sapply(split(File_name, list(File_name$workclass, File_name$sex)), function(x) length(unique(x$age)))`

Comment: @Florian .. Thanks a lot for your time and apologize for hardcoding the File in the Fn definition.Now i commented the hardcoding and Quoted the filename in the arguments. Now the error is "Error in File_name[[W]] : subscript out of bounds". I googled but no insights ..If possible, Pls help me out on this.Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Evan Friedland.. Thanks for your suggestion. I don't wish to hardcode the value in the function , Hence i read the arguments as Out1 to Out 3 and used that as " sapply(split(File_name, list(Out1, Out2)), function(x) length(unique(Out3))) " . But same error as "subscripts out of Bounds ". Even tried directly as  " sapply(split(File_name, list(File_name[[W]], File_name[[S]])), function(x) length(unique(File_name[[A]])))".  Very new to R , Could 't understand the Errors precisely . Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lenin,

The following code worked for me:

```
U <- function(File_name, W, S, A){
  File <- read.csv(File_name, header = TRUE)
  Out1 <- File[[W]]
  Out2 <- File[[S]]
  Out3 <- File[[A]]
  sapply(split(File, list(Out1, Out2)), function(x) length(unique(x[[A]])))
}
U("testing.csv", "workclass", "sex", "age")
```

A few things to notice. I do not call the object that has the File data the same as the string `File_name`. I also do not use `Out3` containing the column of `age` data from the original object within the `sapply` function. We only want to subset our split lists using the string `A` which is "age". Does this help you?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Evan .. Much appreciated..Cheers.